# CNOT gate in Bernstein-Vazirani Algorithm explanation

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms

I am studying the Bernstein-Vazirani Algorithm from the [Qiskit Textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/bernstein-vazirani.html) and I don't understand why specifically the CNOT gate is applied when s[q]=1 (see the code at the end of the linked page). I know that it somehow checks whether it should flip the probability amplitude of that particular state or not, but I can't precisely explain how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have identified yourself the CNOT is used to flip the sign of the coefficient of that particular bitstring. The reason this works is because $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ are the eigenvectors of the $X$ gate with eigenvalues 1 and -1 respectively:

$$
|\psi\rangle \otimes X|-\rangle = 1/\sqrt{2}(|\psi\rangle \otimes X(|0\rangle-|1\rangle))
$$
$$
= 1/\sqrt{2}(|\psi\rangle \otimes (-|0\rangle+|1\rangle))
$$
$$
=-|\psi\rangle \otimes |-\rangle
$$
So the CNOT will flip the sign of the state if the control qubit is 1.